# Не выполняется case на си;

Tags: c++, c, while, switch, case

```
 int act, position;
    char t;
    list_create(l);
    print_menu();
    while(scanf("%d", &act)!=EOF)
    {
        switch(act)
        {
            case 1:
                    t=0;
                    printf("\nЭлемент: ");
                    scanf("%c", &t);
                   break;
            case 2:
                printf("123");
            break;
        }

    }
```

не выполняется case 1 (ввод char просто пропускается)

Comment: Обработка значения, возвращаемого `scanf` неверная

Comment: А как правильно?

Comment: Что означает "ввод char просто пропускается"? А как же насчет `printf("\nЭлемент: ")` - он "пропускается" или нет?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема была в пробеле scanf. Нужно поставить пробел перед %c

Comment: В своих *вопросах* всегда пишите, какие именно были **входные данные**, что **конкретно наблюдаете**, а что предполагали увидеть.

Comment: Ну то есть в вопросе написана полнейшая чушь: с самого начала этот `case 1` прекрасно выполнялся. Почему вопрос до сих пор не исправлен или не удален???

Answer (score 3):

При запросе числа с помощью `scanf` нужно проверить, получили ли результат. Может быть вы просто написали какой-нибудь бардак. Далее при запросе буквы вы можете просто написать длинную строку и дальше ещё нажать **enter**.

Попытаемся исправить :

```
    int sr ; // результат запроса числа
    while(1)    {

Again :      
      sr = scanf("%d", &act); // спрашиваем число
      if(sr == EOF) break; // если поток почему-то закрылся 
      if(sr == 0) {       
        scanf("%c", &t);  // если ввели не число запрашиваем просто букву
        goto Again ; }    // опять спрашиваем число
...
         printf("\nЭлемент: ");
         scanf(" %c", &t); // пишем пробел перед %
                           // чтобы пропустить enter после того как
                           // завели цифру 1
```